# React-Native useState and navigation are interfering

Tags: react-native

Hey Im trying to save data from the textinput with useState. I also have a button which should just bring the user to the past screen. But because both are getting rendered at the time the program gives me a warning and the button is getting disabled.

It says: Cannot update a component while rendering a different component.
And I found out I have to use the useEffect hook but I dont know how to implement it. I tried but It didnt work. I think my problem is in the logic. Hope someone can help me :D

```
  const [text, changeText] = React.useState("")
  useEffect(() => {
   onChangeText();
  }, [] );
  

  return(
    <View>
      <Text>DER NEUE SCREEN</Text>
      <TextInput placeholder="Name your Year" onChangeText={changeText} />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigation.goBack()}><Text>BUTTON</Text></TouchableOpacity>
      <Text>{text}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is `onPress={navigation.goBack()}` a typo? This function will be immediately on render. The correct implementation is `onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}`. Can you share both components?

Comment: Ah man thats embarrassing... Thx mate it was a typo.